# Why does scala allow private case class fields?

Tags: scala

In scala, it is legal to write `case class Foo(private val bar: Any, private val baz: Any)`.

This works like one might hope, `Foo(1, 2) == Foo(1, 2)` and a copy method is generated as well. In my testing, marking the entire constructor as private marks the copy method as private, which is great.

However, either way, you can still do this:

`Foo(1, 2) match { case Foo(bar, baz) => bar } // 1`

So by pattern matching you can extract the value. That seems to render the `private` in `private val bar: Any` more of a suggestion. I saw someone say that "If you want encapsulation, a case class is not the right abstraction", which is a valid point I reckon I agree with. But that raises the question, why is this syntax even allowed if it is arguably misleading?

Comment: Short answer: The unapply method is defined in the companion object and companion object and its class can access each other’s private members.

Comment: How is it any more "misleading" then in java `class A { private int foo; int getFoo() { return foo; }}`? Or in a "regular" (non case) class in scala `class X(private val foo: Int) { def f = foo }`

Comment: @Dima In those cases, I'm exposing foo deliberately.  And the getter can do things like `return foo.readOnlyView` if foo is a mutable object.  The better analogy here is `class X(private val foo: Int) { }` where (short of reflection) it both looks like I can't access `foo` *and* I cannot access `foo`

Comment: @TroyDaniels the point is that `unapply` method (used by pattern matching) is ... well ... just a method. Same as `getFoo` in my example. If you have a private field, you can still have methods that expose it. Case classes are no different in that respect (except that some methods are generated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because case classes were not primary intended to be used with private constructors or fields in the first place. Their main purpose is to model immutable data. As you saw there are workarounds to get the fields so using a private constructor or private fields on a case class is usually a sign of a code smell.

Still, the syntax is allowed, because the code is syntactically and semantically correct - as far as the compiler is concerned. But from the programmer's point of view is at the limit of "does it makes sense to be used it like that?" Probably not.

Marking the constructor of a `case class` as private does not have the effect you want, and it does not make the `copy` method private, at least not in Scala 2.13.

LATER EDIT: In Scala 3, marking the constructor as private, does make the `apply` and `copy` methods private. This change was also developed for Scala 2 and can be found [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7702) - but it was delayed for the 2.14 future release. The reason it can't go into Scala 2.13 is because it's a breaking change.

```
case class Foo private (bar: Int, baz: Int)
```

The only thing I can't do is this:

```
val foo1 = new Foo(1, 2)   // no constructor accessible from here
```

But I can do this:

```
  val foo2 = Foo(1, 2)       // ok
  val foo3 = Foo.apply(1, 2) // ok
  val foo4 = foo2.copy(4)    // ok - Foo(4,2)
```

A `case class` as it's name implies means the object is precisely intended to be pattern matched  or "caseable" - that means you can use it like this:

```
case Foo(x, y) =>       // do something with x and y
```

Or this:

```
val foo2 = Foo(1, 2)
val Foo(x, y) = foo2    // equivalent to the previous
```

Otherwise why would you mark it as a `case class` instead of a `class` ?
Sure, one could argue a `case class` is more convenient because it comes with a lot of methods (rest assured, all that comes with an overhead at runtime as a trade-off for all those created methods) but if privacy is what you are after, they don't bring anything to the table on that.

A `case class` creates a companion object with an `unapply` method inside which when given an instance of your `case class`, it will deconstruct/destructure it into its initialized fields. This is also called an *extractor* method.

The companion object and it's class can access each other's members - that includes private constructor and fields. That is how it was designed. Now `apply` and `unapply` are public methods defined on the companion object which means - you can still create new objects using `apply`, and if your fields are private - you can still access them from `unapply`.

Still, you can overwrite them both in the companion object if you really want your `case class` to be private. Most of the times though, it won't make sense to do so, unless you have some really specific requirements:

```
  case class Foo2 private (private val bar: Int, private val baz: Int)

  object Foo2 {
    private def apply(bar: Int, baz: Int) = new Foo2(bar, baz)
    private def unapply(f: Foo2): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(f.bar, f.baz)
  }

  val foo11          = new Foo2(1, 2)   // won't compile
  val foo22          = Foo2(1, 2)       // won't compile
  val foo33          = Foo2.apply(1, 2) // won't compile
  val Foo2(bar, baz) = foo22            // won't compile

  println(Foo2(1, 2) == Foo2(1, 2))     // won't compile

  val sum = foo22 match {
    case Foo2(x, y) => x + y            // won't compile
  }
```

Still, you can see the contents of `Foo2` by printing it, because case classes also overwrite `toString` and you can't make that private, so you'll have to overwrite it to print something else. I will leave that to you to try out.

```
 print(foo11)  // Foo2(1,2)
```

As you see, a `case class` brings multiple access points to it's constructor and fields. This example was just for understanding the concept. It is not an example of a good design. Usually in OOP, you need an instance of some class, to perform operations on it. So a class that you cannot instantiate at all is no more useful than a Scala `object`. If you find yourself blocking all ways to create an instance of some class or case class, that's a sign you probably need an `object` instead since `object` is already a singleton in Scala.

Comment: I do wonder if it should have been allowed, even if it is technically correct. I'm not planning to actually use it, mind, I'm simply in the situation where I have an immutable data structure that may change as the project continues. However it probably makes sense to implement that by having a normal class that wraps an internal case class.

Comment: `case class Foo private (private val bar: Any,  private val baz: Any);

val f = Foo(1, 2);
val g = f.copy(bar = 1);`

incidentally, I looked at the code I tested again, using scastie.scala-lang.org it compiles under scala 2, but not scala 3. I was only half right though, as the actual difference is that 3 marks the generated apply method as private. copy is still public.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer: you can make the copy method inaccessible by adding a private method named `copy`:

```
case class Foo3(private val x: Int) {
  private def copy: Foo3 = this
}

Foo3(1).copy(x = 2) // won't compile ("method ... cannot be accessed")
```