# Best design for a scala case class style object that needs private data

Tags: scala, case-class

I have some data which I need to pass around, which, after it has been processed, needs to be acknowledged.  Ignoring the acknowledgement, I would write code like

```scala
case class Data(x: Int, y: String)

def process(msg: Any): Unit = 
  msg match 
    case Data(x, y) => processData(x, y)
    case Other(z) => processOther(z)
```

To add the acknowledgement, my first thought would be to add the data needed to send the acknowledgment:

```scala
case class Data(x: Int, y: String, private ack: Acknowledger):
  def acknowledge: Unit = ack.complete(this)

def process(msg: Any): Unit = 
  msg match 
    case data @ Data(x, y) => 
       processData(x, y)
       data.acknowledge
    case Other(z) => processOther(z)
```

This has a few problems.

- As discussed in [Why does scala allow private case class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103502/why-does-scala-allow-private-case-class-fields), the generated `unapply` method will unpack the `ack` field, so I need `case data @ Data(x, y, _)`.
- Someone might try to use the `ack` field directly.
- The user might forget to call `acknowledge`.

If the `ack` field truly was private, that would resolve the first two issues.  The solutions that I can see are to manually define `unapply` methods, or make `Data` a plain class and implement most of the methods that a case class automatically gives me.

Is there a better option?

I think that resolving the third issue is a separate question, but I won't object to quick pointers to a design pattern that addresses it.

Comment: Mixing logic with data is usually a bad idea. I would move the acknowledge outside of the `Data` or make something like `AcknolodgedData` or make `acknowledge` just a simple data field.

Comment: Probably not the "best design",  but your question reminds me that case classes can have more than one parameter lists and generated `toString`, `hashCode`, `equals` and `unapply` will only consider the first parameter list - see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IzvavixKTraK8SGp7BaEMA for a demo of `case class Data(x: Int, y: String)(private val ack: Acknowledger)`.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't agree with "mixing logic with data" always being a bad idea, as suggested in comments ("encapsulation" - incorporating data and the logic that manipulates it into an object – is one of characteristic features of object-oriented programming, which, while having somewhat fallen out of favor lately, still has its place even in scala), what you are trying to do seems to *also* be a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle (which, in my opinion is a much more significant problem).

If the purpose of your class is carrying a message, it should not also have a responsibility of acknowledging the receipt. Acknowledging is the job of whoever receives the message. So, I think something like this makes the most sense:

```
case class Data(x: Int, y: String) 

def process(d: Data, ack: Acknowldger) = msg match { 
  case Data(x, y) => 
     processData(x, y)
     ack.complete(data)
}
```

Let's see if this approach addresses your concerns:

> the generated unapply method will unpack the ack field

Solved (no more ack field)

> Someone might try to use the ack field directly.

Also solved (no more ack field), but for the record, I don't think this is a real concern ... What does it even mean "someone might try ..."? Like, try to do *what*? Send an ack? Well, they could just use your acknowledge method for that, with the same effect? Why would they opt for using ack directly? Just to irritate you? :D
I am actually not a fan of using `private` fields in scala, at least, for immutable members and objects, which 99% of cases are supposed to be anyway for this exact reason: they unnecessarily complicate design, and make it less flexible with zero benefit.

> The user might forget to call acknowledge.

This is actually the only real issue with your original design (another, related one is being able to call acknowledge twice and/or prematurely), and it is *the important one*, making that design "bad". With the approach I suggest, this is easily resolved with a unit test:

```
val ack = mock[Acknowledger]
val data = Data(1, "foo")
process(data, ack)
verify(ack.complete(data))
```